# Manipulate Android Resources at runtime

Tags: android, resources

(Unimportant background) I'm retrieving information of a notification and sending it to another Android Device where the Notification is exactly cloned and displayed.

```
Notification.Builder nb = new Builder(mContext); 
nb.set...;
nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 
Notification notification = nb.build();
```

This creates a notification with an Icon "R.drawable.ic_launcher" which is displayed in the Status bar and also in the android.R.id.icon ImageView of Notification contentview. I need to change both based on a bitmap. The image in contentview can be changed like this:

```
notification.contentView.setImageViewBitmap(RemoteViewsData.iconID, nd.contentView.icon);
```

I need a way how to change the Icon in the statusbar.(i.imgur.com/2Yu56.png)

Ideas:

1. Assign an ID at runtime. Is this possible?
2. Don't change the ID but change the resource file (in storage) it is linked to. Where the resources are stored, are they writable.

Comment: Could you be more clear? what is `another Android System`? what do you mean by `Notification is rebuild`?. Explain with some code please.

Comment: I'm getting all valuable information of a notification line ContentView, BigcontentView, Icons, Sound Uri, Tickertext and so on. That means when a Notification occurs (e.g. an E-Mail) on device A the notification content is extracted and send to an other android Device B. On device B the information is put together and the same notification is rebuild. Rebuild means the Notification on device A is exactly cloned on device B.

Comment: Still not clear what your question is. What are you trying to accomplish here? Show us some code of how you are doing it until now.

Comment: Notification.Builder nb = new Builder(mContext);
nb.set...
nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Notification notification = nb.build();

This creates a notification with an Icon "R.drawable.ic_launcher" which is displayed in the Status bar and also in the android.R.id.icon ImageView of Notification contentview.
I need to change both base on a bitmap I have. The image in contentview can be changed like this:
notification.contentView.setImageViewBitmap(RemoteViewsData.iconID, nd.contentView.icon);
I need a way how to change the Icon in the statusbar.(http://i.imgur.com/2Yu56.png)

Comment: Try updating your question with that. It will be easier to read.